# Converting binary to string then back to binary

Tags: php, binary

This is the synopsis: the PHP code is an interpreter of commands given in a terminal-like fashion, so as a string. Basically PHP receives a string argument, interprets it based on a given regular expression and then execute it. Here, the code receives a string similar to

```
ftp>fput -file(contents-of-file)
```

In this case, the code will ftp-fput a string to a given server. Works fine when  file is ASCII. Now if the file is binary (ie, an image), the regex will bug and even if it wouldnt I want to encode the binary contents of the file so it can fit into the command string. I then need to be able to decode it on the interpreter side. I've tried base64 encode/decode, hex2bin bin2hex, pack unpack, but the file ftp'd always ends up not being readable by browser. The generated file, when attempted to be opened on Linux, generates an error like

```
Fatal error reading PNG image file: PNG file corrupted by ASCII-conversion
```

Any suggestions or clarification requests welcome,

Thanks

Comment: You have to be more specific. Give an example of a file you want to send, the command you used, and how it ended up.

Answer (score 4):

That specific error occurs thanks to smartness on behalf of the PNG developers.  They included a carriage return and a newline as part of the standard PNG header, just to catch this problem.  It looks like the expected CRLF is being translated to just a LF.

Can you show us the regexes you're using?  This really should not happen unless you're expressly converting `\r` to `\n` (or discarding it) at some point.

Comment: Right on the spot, Charles. Images with other extensions go smooth sailing. And when I compare the binaries of the original png with the one produced, I can spot the \r\n at the beginning of file. I don't classify this question as answered yet because I'm still working on the regex to get rid of the CRLF.